# buenas noches, ayuda con JSONArray y JSONObject

Tags: android

tengo el sig código en un PHP

```
$json=array();
    if(isset($_GET["address"])){
        $documento=$_GET["address"];
        $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);
        $consulta="select subject, created from dit_ticket__cdata inner join dit_ticket on dit_ticket__cdata.ticket_id=dit_ticket.ticket_id inner join dit_user_email on dit_user_email.user_id=dit_ticket.user_id where dit_user_email.address='{$documento}'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta); 
if($registro=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){
        $result["subject"]=$registro[0];
        $result["created"]=$registro[1];
        $json['usuario'][]=$result;                   
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        echo json_encode($json);
```

y en Android Studio lo manejo así:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("usuario");
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        try {
            jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(0);
            System.out.println(" motivo "+jsonObject.optString("subject"));
            System.out.println(" creado "+jsonObject.optString("created"));
```

ahí me muestra el primer registro de los 3 registrados pero si agrego esta linea al archivo PHP 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya no me muesta ningun registro esa linea solo la ocupo para que me muestre solo 1 registro ayuda por favor

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. En MySQL, para mostrar un solo registro lo que debes usar es `LIMIT`, poniendo la consulta así: `$consulta="select subject, created from dit_ticket__cdata inner join dit_ticket on dit_ticket__cdata.ticket_id=dit_ticket.ticket_id inner join dit_user_email on dit_user_email.user_id=dit_ticket.user_id where dit_user_email.address='{$documento}' LIMIT 1";` cuando agregas un `WHERE` lo que haces es agregar una condición, y la consulta no arroja datos si esa condición no se cumple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si agregas  a tu consulta:

```
and status_id =1
```

y no obtienes ningún valor significa que ninguno de los valores de tu primer consulta tiene status_id con valor 1

Si usas tu query anterior puedes limitar a mostrar solo un registro mediante [LIMIT](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-mysql-limit-clause/).

> [LIMIT](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-mysql-limit-clause/) En MySQL, la cláusula LIMIT se usa con la instrucción
>   SELECT para restringir el número de filas en el conjunto de
>   resultados. La Cláusula de Límite acepta uno o dos argumentos que son
>   offset y count. El valor de ambos parámetros puede ser cero o enteros
>   positivos.

Ejemplo:

```
$consulta="select ........ where dit_user_email.address='{$documento}' LIMIT 1";
```